# Applying an ex command to a visual selection or text object

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions, ex-mode

Is it possible to apply an ex command to something smaller than a line? For instance, I tried to define a mapping that would remove an \emph{} from the enclosed word. The best I could do was:

`nnoremap dsi vaW:s/\\emph{//\|s/}//<cr>`

It turns out that this does not operate on the selection but rather on the line.

PS. I am satisfied with the comments to the effect that `:s` can operate on selections if `\%V` is placed at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: How about `noremap dsi vaW:s/\%V\\emph{//\|s/}//<cr>` ? See `:h /\%V`. And, unless you have a special need, always use `noremap`, not `nmap`, if you want to avoid surprises. Also your map won't like spaces (more than one emphasized/enclosed word).

Comment: Not that I know of. If you had surround installed you could do something like ``nmap dsf ds{dF\`` (I mean `nmap` since I want `ds{` to call the surround mapping.)

Comment: not really. Ex commands always refer to complete lines. You can work around it by yanking your visual selected range, use some functions to work with the yanked text and replace the yank back. Alternative solutions include using Dr.Chips [vis.vim plugin](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VIS) or using the `\%V` atom specifically for the `:s` command

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VIS 's :B command  will do what you want -- it applies the command to the visual block selection.